# how to set focus on diffrent element while click on an image button in the aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one image button in my aspx page. When click that button it will calls one javascript function like

```
function skiptoaccess() {

    if (document.getElementById("ctl00_txtBox") != null)
        document.getElementById("ctl00_txtBox").focus();
}
```

In that function I tried to set focus for text box when clicking the imagebutton I got the error message like ""htmlfile: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus."
". So anyone please let me know the solution for that?
My imagebutton and textbox like below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" Style="display: none;" runat="server">Click 'OK' to continue and reload the page or 'Cancel' to close the window</asp:TextBox>

<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/images/visuallyimpaired_Disabled.gif" ID="imgbtnAccessibility" runat="server" AlternateText="Accessibility" ToolTip="Accessibility" OnClientClick=" return skiptoaccess();" />`
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't give focus to an element that is hidden.

Remove `Style="display: none;"` if you want to be able to give it focus, or make it visible when the button is clicked.

Comment: Here's a working example of how it should probably look in your source http://jsfiddle.net/rjr6B/ - Is this how yours looks?